# how to avoid nested typescript if statements using let x: type | undefined = variable

Tags: typescript, nested-if, union-types

Is there a better way to handle checking for type | type2 when a variable is defined as type | type2? As an example, I have this small code snippet:

```
    if (e) {
        let targetElement: Element | undefined = e.toElement;
        if (targetElement) {
            let medicineCategory: string | null = targetElement.textContent;
            if (medicineCategory) {
                $('#selected-medicine-info').text(medicineCategory);
            }
        }
    }
```

Putting a bunch of checks in the code for !undefined and !null seems really inelegant, especially if this nested more deeply.

I settled on this, which is a little better reading, and I can tell easily the value of textContent was null:

```
    let targetElement: Element | undefined = e.toElement;
    if (targetElement) {
        let medicineCategory: string | null = (targetElement.textContent !== null) ? targetElement.textContent : "null";
        $('#selected-medicine-info').text(medicineCategory);
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16 https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Comment: I settled on this, which is a little better reading, and I can tell easily the value of textContent was null:
        let targetElement: Element | undefined = e.toElement;
        if (targetElement) {
            let medicineCategory: string | null = (targetElement.textContent !== null) ? targetElement.textContent : "null";
            $('#selected-medicine-info').text(medicineCategory);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LoDash. `_.get` will automatically do the error handling. If `e` is `null`/`undefined`, or if the path doesn't exist, it will simply return a default value. If you don't provide a default, it will return `undefined`.

```
// _.get takes an `object`, `path`, and `default`. Typescript will infer
// that the type is `string`, because the default is an empty string 
// (thanks Lodash)

const medicineCategory = _.get(e, ['toElement', 'textContext'], '');

if (medicineCategory) 
   $('#selected-medicine-info').text(medicineCategory);
```

See more here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get

There is a reason LoDash is npm's most depended on library. (https://www.npmjs.com/ see bottom of page).